Open .py file in Spyder from Windows Explorer
I want to be able to open a .py file in Spyder directly from a double-click in Windows Explorer. So far I've successfully: right-click a .py file > Open with > Spyder 6 > Always. Once that is set, double clicking the .py file opens Spyder, but NOT the file itself. The editor has a temp.py file open, but not the file I clicked on in Explorer.
Note this is a standalone install of Spyder, not with Anaconda. I've seen solutions that use a .bat file as the "default program" but they are based around apps/scripts that appear to be specific to the Anaconda install, not the standalone install.

Windows 11 Home 24H2
Spyder version: 6.0.2 (standalone)

Python version: 3.11.10 64-bit
Qt version: 5.15.8
PyQt5 version: 5.15.9



